# File auditing for shared network drives

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, file-sharing

We got hit by Cryptolocker a month back or so, and never had file auditing set up, so there was no way to identify what user it originated from.

I've gone into Admin Tools > Local Security Policy > Local Policy > Audit Policy > and enabled Success and Failure on Object Access.

I then went to the audit settings for the root folder of the shared drives and selected to monitored "Domain Users" for Write Attributes, Delete, and Delete subfolders and files.

But the event log is just flooded with "Detailed File Share" event 5145, " A network share object was checked to see whether client can be granted desired access"

I really don't need need to see these events, and just want to track if a file is modified, in case we get hit by the cryptolocker again. Is there something else I need to do to only get those kind of events?

Is there a tool that does a better job than Windows ﻿Event Log?

Comment: `just want to track if a file is modified, in case we get hit by the cryptolocker again` - I'm failing to see how this is going to be helpful. Once the event is logged it's too late, the damage is done. Wouldn't your efforts be better put to use preventing this in the first place, via user education, better AV management, email and firewall filtering, etc., etc,?

Comment: So we can isolate the computer / user that it started from?  How would this not be useful?

Comment: Once the event is logged, the system where the event is logged is already infected and the virus has already spread or is spreading organization wide, which means you should isolate ALL systems. Is it your intention that you're going to set up monitoring for this very event, fire off a real time notification, track down the system and isolate it before further damage is done? I don't mean any snark with this comment, but good luck with that.

Comment: Yes the damage is done, but knowing where it originated from it still valuable information.  Your logic makes no sense, there is no downside on having that information.

Comment: I didn't say there was a downside. My take on your question is that you're doing this as some kind of preventive measure, which is not likely to be very effective. If I've misunderstood, then my apologies.

Comment: Additionally, the value in doing this isn't obvious to me. If it's for the purpose of identifying the originating system then I'd say your enterprise AV management station is a better resource for tracking that down. Otherwise, the value proposition is lost on me. Can you elaborate on what potential value you see in this so that I can understand it from your point of view?

Comment: Also (and I'm not piling on, I'm just trying to understand the effectiveness of this method), people modify files all day every day. You're going to have hundreds if not thousands of audit events in your logs. If an outbreak occurs how is it that you're planning to sift through hundreds or thousands of log entries looking for the source of the infection and how will you recognise it and distinguish it from all of the other log entries?

Comment: When we got hit by it previously, it was one user and it infected a network drive we have that is available to everyone in the company, and it just went down the list of all the files in that drive, encrypting them to .ecc files.  We are not a huge company, so if I see a bunch of logs of a single user modifying a different file every minute or so, chances are that is the infected one.  Once that is identified, we can do more research into what they were doing, and take the appropriate measures.

Answer (score 1):

When using the legacy audit settings located at:

Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > Audit Policy > Object Access, that is very coarse and may create a lot of noise, depending on the objects may have auditing enabled.

If you set legacy auditing to Not Configured, and enable Advanced Auditing located at:

Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > Advanced Audit Policy Configuration > Object Access

You can enable only the subcategories that you need, in this case File System.

Then, on the file system, enable only the type(s) of auditing that you need on the top-level folders:
[image]